# Django: Message error does not appear when using option value for POST

Tags: django, post, select, message

When the user selects the following option values--it POSTs successfully. However, I am trying to send an error message when the user clicks "submit" without selecting any. When it "submits" without selecting, it gives an error:  MultiKeyValueDictKeyError: 'venue'. How do I code it properly for error messages to show when the user submits without selecting? I appreciate your thorough feedback!

views.py

```
def add(request):
    if not 'user_id' in request.session:
        return redirect('/chrisgrafil')
    if request.method!='POST':
        messages.error(request, 'Please select the following options')
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        Ticket.objects.create(venue=request.POST['venue'], quantity=request.POST['quantity'], loop=request.POST['loop'], purchaser=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']))
        return redirect ('/confirmation')
```

dashboard.html

```
<form action="/add" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="text-center">
                            {% if messages %}
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger p-2 pb-3">
                                <a class="close font-weight-normal initialism" data-dismiss="alert" href="#"><samp>×</samp></a> 
                                {{message}}
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <label><strong>Location of Venue:</strong></label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="venue">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                            <option value="San Bernardino">San Bernardino</option>
                            <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
                            <option value="Riverside">Riverside</option>
                        </select>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    venue=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price=models.DecimalField(default=25.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    loop=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add the `required` attribute to the `<select>` element. It is better to handle frontend issues on the frontend.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="venue" required>
...
</select>
```

Also, it seems you are structuring your view incorrectly. I would still handle the error I showed you above, but for future reference you should structure your views like so:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.session.get('user_id', '')
        if not user_id:
            return redirect('/chrisgrafil')
        purchaser = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        venue = request.POST.get('venue', '')
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity', '')
        loop = request.POST.get('loop', '')

        if not venue:
            messages.error(request, 'Please select the following options')
            return redirect('/dashboard')

        Ticket.objects.create(venue=venue, quantity=quantity, loop=loop, purchaser=purchaser)
        return redirect('/confirmation')
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, Hybrid! It is certainly a lot easier with the "required." The suggested views.py seems a lot more easier to follow--I'll keep this as future reference.